# Creature not found in Pokédex!

Tags: riddle, story, haiku

I'm going to try this format.

> A creature pops up!
> It's not in your Pokédex
> And it wants to play.
>
> "Let's play hide n' seek!"
> "I'll hide first. No need to count!"
> Now it disappeared.
>
> So you searched and searched.
> And searched and searched until you
> could search not at all.
>
> So then you cheated.
> "That creature's not in the 'Dex!"
> "It cheats, so I will."
>
> You made a method
> To find the undexed creature.
> And you think it works.
>
> You walk peacefully.
> And now there are *2* creatures!
> "Come on and find us!"
>
> Knowing they will cheat,
> You use the algorithm.
> Now there are *20*!!
>
> Violent curses
> Come out of your mouth. "I WILL "
> "END THIS FOREVER!"
>
> The same old function.
> Now everything dies. Too much.
> Reboot. Only one.
>
> Nothing was saved. The
> creature asked the same question.
> You said, "No." Report!

What is this mischievous, mysterious creature not found in your Pokédex?

Hint:

> It's not related to Pokémon in any way.

Hint 2:

> I wish it was this colorful in real life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:

> You are trying to debug a program, but the fixes you implement create more bugs in the process. Fed up, you revert your changes, so you can face the original bug again, hopefully with more luck this time :)

Comment: You did it! YAY!!

Comment: 99 little bugs in the code, 99 little bugs in the code. Take one down, patch it around, 127 little bugs in the code...